# Laravel 5.3 Form Request Validation required_if and min rules

Tags: laravel, validation

I use Form Request Validation in one of my Laravel projects, and want to validate `country_id` but only if `bak_leaflet` ist set to 0. In my `FormRequestFile` i have the following rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'country_id' => 'required_if:bak_leaflet,0',
        ...
    ];
}
```

This works absolutely fine, but when `bak_leaflet` is `0`, then `country_id` also needs to be larger than 1:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'country_id' => 'required_if:bak_leaflet,0|min:1',
        ...
    ];
}
```

However, the `min:1` rule gets ignored completely. How can I make sure the validation works how I need it to?

Comment: "min" is the minimum length not minimum value ;)

Comment: not true: `For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a validation extender in your AppServiceProvider's boot() method, like this:

```
\Validator::extend('min_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $data = $validator->getData();
    if (isset($data[$parameters[0]]) && $data[$parameters[0]] == $parameters[1] && (int)$value < $parameters[2]) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Then write your validation rule like this:

```
'country_id' => 'required_if:bak_leaflet,0|min_if:bak_leaflet,0,1',
```

Additionally you will need to add

```
'min_if'          => 'Your validation message',
```

into **resources/lang/en/validation.php** or pass to your **$this->validate()** as third paramater

Comment: I'm not able to get the request value. IE, I would need to do "'min_if' =>  'The :attribute must have at least :min items." but it's shown as "The MyInput must have at least :min items.". I've also tried with :value but no luck so far. Any clue?

Comment: You need to add `$validator->addReplacer();` in your `Validator::extend();`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the answer of @avik-aghajanyan and added the method to my form request file as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;

class StoreArticle extends FormRequest
{
    public function __construct(ValidationFactory $validationFactory)
    {
        $validationFactory->extend('min_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $data = $validator->getData();
            if (isset($data[$parameters[0]]) && $data[$parameters[0]] == $parameters[1] && (int)$value < $parameters[2]) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
    ....
```